# ERESYE get list of rules that have been added to an engine?

Tags: module, erlang, rules, rule-engine

Is there a way to get a list of rules that have been added to an ERESYE rules engine? Imagine I have a function like this:

```
start () ->
  eresye:start(engine),
  eresye:add_rule(engine, {module, a_rule_function}),
  eresye:add_rule(engine, {module, another_rule_function}),
  %% do some other stuff
  ok.
```

Is there a way, given the name of the engine, to retrieve an array of all the rule functions that have been added? I could keep track of this myself but it would be easier if I could just do something like `eresye:list_rules(engine)`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/TypedLambda/eresye/), it looks like the rules are stored in the form of a `eresye_tree_list` in the process state. You could fetch the entire "rete" and extract the tree with something like:

```
[_, _, Tree, _, _] = eresye:get_rete(engine).
```

Then, you could use the functions from the `eresye_tree_list` module to traverse the `Tree` and to convert it into a list. It probably makes sense to implement this as part of the `eresye` module itself.